# Strapi CORS error although middleware is configured

Tags: node.js, axios, cors, strapi

I know there are similar questions out here, but nothing helped me so far. I'm getting a cors error in strapi v4.5.3 although I have configured it to allow the origin. Strapi doesn't seem to take the origins I'm using. My middleware.ts looks like this:

```
export default [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  {
    name: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      enabled: true,
      origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGINS
        ? process.env.CORS_ORIGINS.split(', ')
        : '*',
      credentials: true,
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
      headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'Accept'],
      keepHeaderOnError: true,
    },
  },
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
]
```

with the following .env value:

```
CORS_ORIGINS=http://localhost:1337, http://localhost:6006, http://localhost:18082, https://portal-cms.example.de, https://portal-cms.example.bop
```

When I'm calling from `localhost:6006` or `localhost:18082` to `localhost:1337` everything works fine. My dev server is available at `https://portal-cms.example.de` and when I try to call it from `localhost:6006` or `localhost:18082` I'm getting the following cors error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portal-cms.example.de/api/contact-infos?locale=en' from origin 'http://localhost:6006' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://portal-cms.example.bop' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

The request is made via axios from a vue component and looks like this:

```
console.log(await axios.get('https://portal-cms.example.de/api/contact-infos?locale=en'))
```

The response header has the value `access-control-allow-origin: https://portal-cms.example.bop`. I would have expected it to have the value that I configured in my `middleware.ts`. Am I understanding it wrong? and is there any way to make this error go away?

Comment: I guess that your env variables are different locally than on the hosting

Comment: no, there are actually the same as I posted in the question